# Animate busy cursor in flex?

Tags: apache-flex

I find out how to replace the busy cursor here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/cursormgr_3.html

However, how do you animate an image for the cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an animated asset created in the Flash IDE and embed it within your Flex app.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create them programmatically, e.g. by extending `flash.display.Sprite`:

Class SampleCursor:

```
public class SampleCursor extends Sprite
    public function SampleCursor() {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, drawCursor);
    }

    public function drawCursor(e:Event):void {
        // Draw cursor using graphics context
        // ...
    }
{
```

And in your Application you just register this class as a cursor (same for other types of cursors like bitmap or flash assets):

```
cursorManager.removeAllCursors();
cursorManager.setCursor(SampleCursor);
```

Hope that helps.